# Set javascript variable to return value of function

Tags: javascript, asp.net, angularjs, rest, wcf

I am trying to set a variable in my controller to the return value of a function. This function is creating a new entry in a table, and then returning its id. When I debug in chrome developer tools, I can see that my function is working correctly and that `response.data` is in fact a number. However, when I try to set a variable to this function call, the value is being set as undefined.

**My AngularJS component:**

```
function saveNewGame($http, gameData) {

    var newGameData = {
        "InvestigatorGroupUserId": gameData.GroupUserId,
        "InvestigatorGroupGameId": gameData.GroupGameId,
        "WithTeacher": gameData.WithTeacher
    };

    $http.post("/APGame.WebHost/play/newGamePlayed", newGameData)
        .then(function(response) {
            return response.data;
        });

}

function controller($http) {

    var model = this;
    var gameData = model.value;
    var gamePlayedId;

    model.startGame = function() {
        gamePlayedId = saveNewGame($http, gameData);
        alert(gamePlayedId);
    };
}

module.component("gameApp",
{
    templateUrl: "/APGame/GameAngular/game-app.html",
    controllerAs: "game",
    bindings: {
        value: "<"
    },
    controller: ["$http", controller]
});
```

**This is what my service call is doing:**

```
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, UriTemplate = "newGamePlayed")]
    int NewGamePlayed(GamePlayedData gamePlayedData);



    public int NewGamePlayed(GamePlayedData gamePlayedData)
    {
        var gamePlayedRepo = _gamePlayedRepo ?? new GamePlayedRepository();

        var newGame = new GamePlayed()
        {
            InvestigatorGroupUserId = gamePlayedData.InvestigatorGroupUserId,
            InvestigatorGroupGameId = gamePlayedData.InvestigatorGroupGameId,
            GameStartTime = DateTime.Now,
            IsComplete = false
        };

        return gamePlayedRepo.Create(newGame);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is because your function is not returning any value thus undefined.

```
$http.post("/APGame.WebHost/play/newGamePlayed", newGameData)
    .then(function(response) {
        // notice that you are returning this value to the function(response) not your saveNewGame function
        return response.data;
    });
```

Due to asynchronous nature of javascript, you should do something like instead. $http.post return a promise object which can be used like following.

```
return $http.post("/APGame.WebHost/play/newGamePlayed", newGameData);
```

And in your calling function.

```
saveNewGame($http, gameData).then(function(response){
    gamePlayedId = response.data;
});
```

Comment: When I do an alert on `gamePlayedId` inside the then function it is returning the correct value. But when I do it outside it is showing `undefined`

Comment: because http.post is asynchronous, the function(response) is called when the http request is completed.

when you alert outside the function, the request is still not completed and the value had not been assigned yet.

Answer (score 2):

Add a promise resolvement listener to the method invoke like following:

```
model.startGame = function() {
    gamePlayedId = saveNewGame($http, gameData)then(function(response) {
      alert(response.data);
    }, function(reason) {
      alert('Failed: ' + reason);
    });
};
```

Return the http.get promise instead of the data

```
function saveNewGame($http, gameData) {

    var newGameData = {
        "InvestigatorGroupUserId": gameData.GroupUserId,
        "InvestigatorGroupGameId": gameData.GroupGameId,
        "WithTeacher": gameData.WithTeacher
    };

    return $http.post("/APGame.WebHost/play/newGamePlayed", newGameData);
}
```

Comment: I've tried something similar to this earlier (and just tried this now) and I get the error: `Cannot read property 'then' of undefined`

Comment: It was possibly because you did not return the $http.get promise. Can you try it?

Comment: I just tried your edited answer with but changed your alert to `alert(response.data)` and it worked, thank you!. How come I have to return the data from the function call to `saveNewGame` instead of the function itself?

Comment: You have to return the $http promise in order to watch the resolvement of it.

Comment: The problem with this is that when I do an alert on `response.data` inside the function call I am getting the proper value. But when I try to return `response.data` and then do an alert on `gamePlayedId` it is returning an object (which does not contain the value). I need to be able to access/store the return value in  `gamePlayedId`